# Apparently inoffensive indefinite integral. (grad student here)

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I've been dealing with these for a while, and tried different things with no success as of yet:

$$
\int \frac {dx}{(x²+c²)\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}
$$

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are real positive numbers.

Trying solving it in Mathematica, if $c=0$, the answer is pretty reasonable, but if $c\neq0$, everything goes bananas, giving imaginary numbers.

Any help, will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks most similar to some kind of elliptic integral, which Mathematica isn't great with. Including "Assumptions->a>0&&b>0&&c>0" may simplify things a bit, but I wouldn't count on it. Also, are you certain you need the _indefinite_ integral? Elliptic integrals are usually easier if you can specify at least one endpoint.

Comment: $$ x = u + \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)   $$

Comment: @Semiclassical: Elliptic integrals are not needed. It can be solved in terms of elementary functions, trigonometric and/or logarithmic.

Comment: @lucian: Yes, I was just realizing that. In my defense, it is _pseudo_-elliptic.

Comment: What is the domain? Looking at the integrand, it seems when $x$ is between $a$ and $b$, the signs of $x-a$ and $x-b$ will be opposite, so you have the square root of a negative number.

Comment: See in the vicinity of p. 287 of the freely available 1921 book [**A Treatise on the Integral Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr01edwauoft) by Joseph Edwards. This book by Edwards is a good place to look for the kind of integral you asked about. The table of contents is sufficiently detailed that I was able to find p. 287 just by looking there.

Answer (score 2):

Using Maple I am obtaining the solution in terms of elementary functions

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take $a > b > 0.$ Let $$\gamma = \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)$$
 $$\delta = \left( \frac{a-b}{2} \right)$$
Let
$$  x = u + \gamma, $$ so the square root part is
$$ \sqrt{u^2 - \delta^2}.  $$
Next, take
$$  u = \delta \cosh t $$

EDIT: The analog of the Weierstrass substitution, when using hyperbolic trig functions, is to take a rational function of $\cosh t$ and $\sinh t$ and turn that into a rational function of another variable. After that one may hope to make progress with partial fractions.

$$   t = \log \left( \frac{1 + w}{1 - w} \right), $$
$$ \cosh t =  \frac{1 + w^2}{1 - w^2},   $$
$$ \sinh t =  \frac{2w}{1 - w^2},   $$
$$ \tanh t =  \frac{2w}{1 + w^2}.   $$
$$ d t =  \frac{2dw}{1 - w^2},   $$
The original is for ordinary trig functions, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Second to the right, and straight on till morning.

That, Peter had told Wendy, was the way to the Neverland; but even birds, carrying maps and consulting them at windy corners, could not have sighted it with these instructions. Peter, you see, just said anything that came into his head.

Typed everything needed to use hyperbolic trig functions in integrals in my permanent Latex file; variable names not consistent with the paragraphs above.

$$   x = \log \left( \frac{1 + w}{1 - w} \right) = 2 \; \mbox{arctanh} \; w, $$
$$ \cosh x =  \frac{1 + w^2}{1 - w^2},   $$
$$ \sinh x =  \frac{2w}{1 - w^2},   $$
$$ \tanh x =  \frac{2w}{1 + w^2}.   $$
$$ d x =  \frac{2dw}{1 - w^2}.   $$
$$ =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= $$
$$  \cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1 $$
$$ 1 - \tanh^2 x = \mbox{sech}^2 \; x    $$
$$ \cosh x + \sinh x = e^x  $$
$$ \cosh x - \sinh x = e^{-x}  $$
$$ \sinh (x+y) = \sinh x \cosh y + \cosh x \sinh y   $$
$$ \cosh  (x+y) = \cosh x \cosh y + \sinh x \sinh y $$
$$  \tanh (x+y) = \frac{\tanh x + \tanh y}{1 + \tanh x \tanh y}  $$
$$ \sinh \frac{x}{2} = \pm \sqrt { \frac{\cosh x - 1}{2}   } $$
$$ \cosh \frac{x}{2} =  \sqrt { \frac{\cosh x + 1}{2}   } $$
$$ \tanh \frac{x}{2} = \pm \sqrt { \frac{\cosh x - 1}{\cosh x + 1}   } = \frac{\cosh x - 1}{\sinh x} = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x + 1} $$
$$  \mbox{arcsinh} \; x = \log \left( x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1} \right) $$
$$  \mbox{arccosh} \; x = \log \left( x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right), \; \; \; x \geq 1 $$
$$  \mbox{arctanh} \; x =  \frac{1}{2} \; \log \left(  \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right), \; \; \; |x | < 1 $$